# Shelf life of marmalade

Tags: sugar

I have 2 jars of orange marmalade with an expiration date of June 1998 and one jar of apricot preserves with an expiration date of November 2000 and they've never been opened so I'm just wondering if they're still good to eat? If this was a zombie apocalypse I would eat it with a spoon no questions asked!! What are your recommendations!?

Comment: 17 years is a bit extreme, but I'd probably eat it if it looked OK. But I'm funny that way.

Comment: @Jolenealaska: I quite agree - especially with the amount of sugar in orange marmelade and possibly added preservatives. As long as the seal is ok...

Comment: No mold on the surface? Likely a good seal. Likely OK to eat.

Answer (score 2):

If the seal is intact it's probably okay. Make sure you hear the "pop" when you open it. If there is no strange smell and it looks alright, then I think it will be fine.

Comment: They are safe to eat, yes. There are no bacteria capable of spoiling food very slowly. If a food is canned in a way such that it lasts for a year, then it will also last for 17 years (does not always apply to food preserved by fermentation).